# How to use this C code to multiply two matrices using Strassen's algorithm?

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-multiplication, strassen

I was looking for an implementation of [Strassen's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) in C, and I've found this code at the end.

To use the `multiply` function:

```
void multiply(int n, matrix a, matrix b, matrix c, matrix d);
```

which multiplies two matrices `a`, `b` and puts the result in `c` (`d` is a intermediary matrix). Matrices `a` and `b` should have the following type:

```
typedef union _matrix 
{
    double **d;
    union _matrix **p;
} *matrix;
```

I have allocated dynamically four matrices `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` (two-dimensional arrays of doubles) and have assigned their addresses to the field `_matrix.d`:

```
#include "strassen.h"

#define SIZE 50 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double ** matA, ** matB, ** matC, ** matD;
    union _matrix ma, mb, mc, md; 
    int i = 0, j = 0, n;

    matA = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double *) * SIZE);
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        matA[i] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * SIZE); 
    // Do the same for matB, matC, matD.

    ma.d = matA;
    mb.d = matB;
    mc.d = matC;
    md.d = matD;

    // Initialize matC and matD to 0.

    // Read n.

    // Read matA and matB.

    multiply(n, &ma, &mb, &mc, &md);
    return 0;
}
```

This code successfully compiles but crashes with `n` > `BREAK`.

strassen.c :

```
#include "strassen.h"

/* c = a * b */
void multiply(int n, matrix a, matrix b, matrix c, matrix d)
{
    if (n <= BREAK) {
      double sum, **p = a->d, **q = b->d, **r = c->d;
      int i, j, k;

      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
         for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (sum = 0., k = 0; k < n; k++)
               sum += p[i][k] * q[k][j];
            r[i][j] = sum;
         }
    } else {
        n /= 2;
        sub(n, a12, a22, d11);
        add(n, b21, b22, d12);
        multiply(n, d11, d12, c11, d21);
        sub(n, a21, a11, d11);
        add(n, b11, b12, d12);
        multiply(n, d11, d12, c22, d21);
        add(n, a11, a12, d11);
        multiply(n, d11, b22, c12, d12);
        sub(n, c11, c12, c11);
        sub(n, b21, b11, d11);
        multiply(n, a22, d11, c21, d12);
        add(n, c21, c11, c11);
        sub(n, b12, b22, d11);
        multiply(n, a11, d11, d12, d21);
        add(n, d12, c12, c12);
        add(n, d12, c22, c22);
        add(n, a21, a22, d11);
        multiply(n, d11, b11, d12, d21);
        add(n, d12, c21, c21);
        sub(n, c22, d12, c22);
        add(n, a11, a22, d11);
        add(n, b11, b22, d12);
        multiply(n, d11, d12, d21, d22);
        add(n, d21, c11, c11);
        add(n, d21, c22, c22);
    }
}

/* c = a + b */
void add(int n, matrix a, matrix b, matrix c)
{
    if (n <= BREAK) {
        double **p = a->d, **q = b->d, **r = c->d;
        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
           for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
              r[i][j] = p[i][j] + q[i][j];
    } else {
        n /= 2;
        add(n, a11, b11, c11);
        add(n, a12, b12, c12);
        add(n, a21, b21, c21);
        add(n, a22, b22, c22);
    }
}

/* c = a - b */
void sub(int n, matrix a, matrix b, matrix c)
{
    if (n <= BREAK) {
        double **p = a->d, **q = b->d, **r = c->d;
        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
           for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
              r[i][j] = p[i][j] - q[i][j];
    } else {
        n /= 2;
        sub(n, a11, b11, c11);
        sub(n, a12, b12, c12);
        sub(n, a21, b21, c21);
        sub(n, a22, b22, c22);
    }
}
```

strassen.h:

```
#define BREAK 8   

typedef union _matrix {
    double **d;
    union _matrix **p;
} *matrix;

/* Notational shorthand to access submatrices for matrices named a, b, c, d */

#define a11 a->p[0]
#define a12 a->p[1]
#define a21 a->p[2]
#define a22 a->p[3]
#define b11 b->p[0]
#define b12 b->p[1]
#define b21 b->p[2]
#define b22 b->p[3]
#define c11 c->p[0]
#define c12 c->p[1]
#define c21 c->p[2]
#define c22 c->p[3]
#define d11 d->p[0]
#define d12 d->p[1]
#define d21 d->p[2]
#define d22 d->p[3]
```

My question is how to use the function `multiply` (how to implement the matrix).

[strassen.h](http://math.ewha.ac.kr/~jylee/SciComp/sc-crandall/strassen.h)

[strassen.c](http://math.ewha.ac.kr/~jylee/SciComp/sc-crandall/strassen.c)

Comment: Don't cast the the return value from `malloc()` in C.

Comment: Instead of dumping such large code piece, please corner the problem and clearly explain what it is! And also tell what you tried and what you suspicion? Your current version of the question might make people itchy

Comment: `n` is uninitialiazed in your `main`

Comment: Check this great document on implementing strassen algorithm http://software.intel.com/file/24473implementation and also the code posted by @Tudor : http://software.intel.com/file/24473

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [Atom said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9602888/648265), you need to correctly initialize `matrix.p` for both matrices.

1) First of all, your `matrix` is a [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28computer_science%29) so `p` essentially becomes `d` interpreted as `_matrix **` which doesn't make sense here - that's why it crashes. You probably need to make `matrix` a `struct` instead.
Finally, `p` is by definition an array of submatrices so it should be a `struct _matrix *` (and you'll need to `malloc` the actual array when needed) or `struct _matrix[4]` (which is impossible :) ).

```
typedef struct _matrix 
{
    double **d;
    struct _matrix *p;
} *matrix;
```

2) Now, let's see what `p` should be.

```
                           │
A.d ->  d1 -> a[1,1] a[1,2]│a[1,3] a[1,4]
        d2 -> a[2,1] a[2,2]│a[2,3] a[2,4]
             ─────────────────────────────
        d3 -> a[3,1] a[3,2]│a[3,3] a[3,4]
        d4 -> a[4,1] a[4,2]│a[4,3] a[4,4]
                           │
```

`p` points to an array of `matrix` structures! The peculiarity is to make `d`'s of those structures point to inside *A*
in such a way that `(p[k].d)[i][j]` is the respective submatrix's element:

```
p[0].d -> p01 -> a[1,1]    p[1].d -> p11 -> a[1,3]
          p02 -> a[2,1]              p12 -> a[2,3]

p[2].d -> p21 -> a[3,1]    p[3].d -> p31 -> a[3,3]
          p22 -> a[4,1]              p32 -> a[4,3]
```

Can you now deduce the algorithm to initialize `p` for square *A* of an arbitrary even size?

And WHEN to initialize it in the first place? ;)

Comment: I think with the above definition the author wanted to introduce a hierarchical storage for matrices. Say you have a 8 by 8 matrix and the value of BREAK is 2, you'd first allocate p to represent 4 sub matrices, and in turn this p will represent 4 matrices of d. So you're allocating 1 + 4 times for p and 16 times for d.

Or else why would anyone want to divide and conquer addition of matrices?

Answer (score 3):

When n > BREAK, the matrix multiplication algorithm uses a hierarchical matrix representation (the field `p` of `union _matrix`, not the field `d`).

You need to adjust your code for the hierarchical representation when allocating memory and when initializing matrices `a` and `b`.

Comment: The problem is i didn't figure out how to do this, i have used the standard dynamic allocation for a tow dimensional array but the code crash when it comes to n > break, thanks

Comment: Do you mean "two" instead of "tow"?